# Ansible: Print path and contents of multiple files

Tags: ssh, ansible

I am trying to write a playbook that scans a host for the `authorized_keys` file, and then prints out the path and contents of the file.

Every attempt I have made and all the researching I have done and I am still unable to get the behaviour that I want, which is the following:

- For each instance of the found file, print:
- path to file
- contents of file

Here is the playbook:

```
---

- name: Show File Contents
  vars_prompt:
    - name: host
      prompt: Enter host(s) to search
      private: no

    - name: file
      prompt: Enter file to show the contents of
      private: no

  hosts: "{{ host }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Find Files
      find:
         patterns: "{{ file }}"
         recurse: true
         paths: /
      register: files_matched

    - name: Cat authorized keys
      shell: cat {{ item.path }}
      register: cat
      loop: "{{ files_matched.files }}"

    - name: Print output
      loop: "{{ cat | json_query('results[*].stdout') }}"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.results }}"

  become: true

...
```

Here is the output when the above playbook is run against a single host:

```
TASK [Print output] ****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ansible-testinghost.local] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "cat /root/.ssh/authorized_keys",
            "delta": "0:00:00.003527",
            "end": "2022-04-10 14:56:27.867035",
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "cat /root/.ssh/authorized_keys",
                    "_uses_shell": true,
                    "argv": null,
                    "chdir": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "executable": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "stdin": null,
                    "stdin_add_newline": true,
                    "strip_empty_ends": true,
                    "warn": true
                }
            },
            "item": {
                "atime": 1649599428.4008615,
                "ctime": 1648947238.992,
                "dev": 64768,
                "gid": 0,
                "gr_name": "root",
                "inode": 661181,
                "isblk": false,
                "ischr": false,
                "isdir": false,
                "isfifo": false,
                "isgid": false,
                "islnk": false,
                "isreg": true,
                "issock": false,
                "isuid": false,
                "mode": "0600",
                "mtime": 1648947238.992,
                "nlink": 1,
                "path": "/root/.ssh/authorized_keys",
                "pw_name": "root",
                "rgrp": false,
                "roth": false,
                "rusr": true,
                "size": 0,
                "uid": 0,
                "wgrp": false,
                "woth": false,
                "wusr": true,
                "xgrp": false,
                "xoth": false,
                "xusr": false
            },
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2022-04-10 14:56:27.863508",
            "stderr": "",
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "stdout": "",
            "stdout_lines": []
        },
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "cat /home/ansible/.ssh/authorized_keys",
            "delta": "0:00:00.003548",
            "end": "2022-04-10 14:56:28.138414",
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "cat /home/ansible/.ssh/authorized_keys",
                    "_uses_shell": true,
                    "argv": null,
                    "chdir": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "executable": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "stdin": null,
                    "stdin_add_newline": true,
                    "strip_empty_ends": true,
                    "warn": true
                }
            },
            "item": {
                "atime": 1649587940.6308339,
                "ctime": 1649458786.3099895,
                "dev": 64768,
                "gid": 1001,
                "gr_name": "ansible",
                "inode": 661196,
                "isblk": false,
                "ischr": false,
                "isdir": false,
                "isfifo": false,
                "isgid": false,
                "islnk": false,
                "isreg": true,
                "issock": false,
                "isuid": false,
                "mode": "0600",
                "mtime": 1649458786.3099895,
                "nlink": 1,
                "path": "/home/ansible/.ssh/authorized_keys",
                "pw_name": "ansible",
                "rgrp": false,
                "roth": false,
                "rusr": true,
                "size": 561,
                "uid": 1001,
                "wgrp": false,
                "woth": false,
                "wusr": true,
                "xgrp": false,
                "xoth": false,
                "xusr": false
            },
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2022-04-10 14:56:28.134866",
            "stderr": "",
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "stdout": "ssh key",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "ssh key"
            ]
        },
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "cat /home/primary-admin/.ssh/authorized_keys",
            "delta": "0:00:00.003515",
            "end": "2022-04-10 14:56:28.408766",
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "cat /home/primary-admin/.ssh/authorized_keys",
                    "_uses_shell": true,
                    "argv": null,
                    "chdir": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "executable": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "stdin": null,
                    "stdin_add_newline": true,
                    "strip_empty_ends": true,
                    "warn": true
                }
            },
            "item": {
                "atime": 1649587950.2066748,
                "ctime": 1649495080.4039176,
                "dev": 64768,
                "gid": 1000,
                "gr_name": "primary-admin",
                "inode": 661199,
                "isblk": false,
                "ischr": false,
                "isdir": false,
                "isfifo": false,
                "isgid": false,
                "islnk": false,
                "isreg": true,
                "issock": false,
                "isuid": false,
                "mode": "0600",
                "mtime": 1649495080.4039176,
                "nlink": 1,
                "path": "/home/primary-admin/.ssh/authorized_keys",
                "pw_name": "primary-admin",
                "rgrp": false,
                "roth": false,
                "rusr": true,
                "size": 277,
                "uid": 1000,
                "wgrp": false,
                "woth": false,
                "wusr": true,
                "xgrp": false,
                "xoth": false,
                "xusr": false
            },
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2022-04-10 14:56:28.405251",
            "stderr": "",
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "stdout": "ssh key",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "ssh key"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Which I have summarised to be a list of 3 dictionaries:

```
"msg": [
{},
{},
{}
]
```

How do I get my playbook to print just the path and contents?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Fix the last task *"Print output"*. Otherwise, your code is working as expected. For example, given the files at the remote host for testing

```sh
shell> ssh admin@test_11 'find /tmp -name authorized_keys'
/tmp/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
/tmp/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

```sh
shell> ssh admin@test_11 'cat /tmp/root/.ssh/authorized_keys'
ssh-rsa 111111111111111111
22222222222222222222222222
333333333333 admin@test_12
ssh-rsa 111111111111111111
22222222222222222222222222
333333333333 admin@test_13
```

```sh
shell> ssh admin@test_11 'cat /tmp/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys'
ssh-rsa 111111111111111111
22222222222222222222222222
333333333333 admin@test_12
ssh-rsa 111111111111111111
22222222222222222222222222
333333333333 admin@test_13
```

Running the playbook

```sh
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml
Enter host(s) to search: test_11
Enter file to show the contents of: authorized_keys
```

Set a list

```yaml
    - name: Print output
      set_fact:
        path_content: "{{ cat.results|
                          json_query('[].{path: item.path, content: stdout}') }}"
    - debug:
        var: path_content
```

gives

```yaml
  path_content:
  - content: |-
      ssh-rsa 111111111111111111
      22222222222222222222222222
      333333333333 admin@test_12
      ssh-rsa 111111111111111111
      22222222222222222222222222
      333333333333 admin@test_13
    path: /tmp/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
  - content: |-
      ssh-rsa 111111111111111111
      22222222222222222222222222
      333333333333 admin@test_12
      ssh-rsa 111111111111111111
      22222222222222222222222222
      333333333333 admin@test_13
    path: /tmp/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

, or a dictionary

```yaml
    - name: Print output
      set_fact:
        path_content: "{{ cat.results|
                          json_query('[].{path: item.path, content: stdout}')|
                          items2dict(key_name='path', value_name='content') }}"
    - debug:
        var: path_content
```

gives

```yaml
  path_content:
    /tmp/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys: |-
      ssh-rsa 111111111111111111
      22222222222222222222222222
      333333333333 admin@test_12
      ssh-rsa 111111111111111111
      22222222222222222222222222
      333333333333 admin@test_13
    /tmp/root/.ssh/authorized_keys: |-
      ssh-rsa 111111111111111111
      22222222222222222222222222
      333333333333 admin@test_12
      ssh-rsa 111111111111111111
      22222222222222222222222222
      333333333333 admin@test_13
```

---

If you run the code on multiple hosts collect all results in a dictionary. For example, running the playbook

```sh
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml
Enter host(s) to search: test_11,test_12
Enter file to show the contents of: authorized_keys
```

Set the dictionary of all hosts

```yaml
    - name: Print output of all hosts
      set_fact:
        host_path_content: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                                    zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                                        map('extract', hostvars, 'path_content'))) }}"
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: host_path_content
```

gives

```yaml
  host_path_content:
    test_11:
      /tmp/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys: |-
        ssh-rsa 111111111111111111
        22222222222222222222222222
        333333333333 admin@test_12
        ssh-rsa 111111111111111111
        22222222222222222222222222
        333333333333 admin@test_13
      /tmp/root/.ssh/authorized_keys: |-
        ssh-rsa 111111111111111111
        22222222222222222222222222
        333333333333 admin@test_12
        ssh-rsa 111111111111111111
        22222222222222222222222222
        333333333333 admin@test_13
    test_12:
      /tmp/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys: |-
        ssh-rsa 111111111111111111
        22222222222222222222222222
        333333333333 admin@test_11
        ssh-rsa 111111111111111111
        22222222222222222222222222
        333333333333 admin@test_13
      /tmp/root/.ssh/authorized_keys: |-
        ssh-rsa 111111111111111111
        22222222222222222222222222
        333333333333 admin@test_11
        ssh-rsa 111111111111111111
        22222222222222222222222222
        333333333333 admin@test_13
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted the behaviour to be, thank you so much Vladimir!